# php symfony and apache2 - inst't serving .phtml

Tags: apache, symfony1, apache2, php

I have a problem with apache2 settings (Ubuntu system).
I would like to run symfony project on my localhost but instead of serving .phtml files, browser is trying to download files.

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/ba9be708fc.gif](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/ba9be708fc.gif)

this is my file .host:

> 127.0.0.3 test

this is apache2/sites-available/default file

> < VirtualHost 127.0.0.3:80>
>   ServerName test   DocumentRoot
>   "/home/m/Pr/workspace/php/test/web"
>
> DirectoryIndex frontend_dev.php
>
> < Directory
>   "/home/m/Pr/workspace/php/test/web">
>
> ```
> AllowOverride All
>
> Allow from All
> ```
>
> Alias /sf
>
> /home/m/Pr/workspace/php/test/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf
>
> < Directory
>
> "/home/m/Pr/workspace/php/test/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf">
>
> ```
> AllowOverride All
>
> Allow from All   </Directory>
> ```
>
> and this is .htaccess in /test
>
> RewriteEngine On RewriteRule ^(.*)$
>
> /web/$1 Options +FollowSymLinks
>
> +ExecCGI AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php .phtml

and this is .htaccess in /test/web

> Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
>
> RewriteEngine On
>
> # uncomment the following line, if
>   you are having trouble   # getting
>   no_script_name to work   RewriteBase /
>
> # we skip all files with .something 
>     #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ..+$   #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.html$
>     #RewriteRule .* - [L]
>
> # we check if the .html version is
>   here (caching)   RewriteRule ^$
>   index.html [QSA]   RewriteRule
>   ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]   RewriteCond
>   %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>
> # no, so we redirect to our front
>   web controller   RewriteRule ^(.*)$
>   index.php [QSA,L]

Another problem is I think apache don't read  .htaccess files.

What am i doing wrong? Maybe I forgot about something?  Please, help me becouse i have no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the AddType directive in your Apache config - I'm not sure adding it to .htaccess will work.

Add this line to either `/etc/apache2/mods.enabled/php.conf` or `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php .phtml
```

Restart Apache and retry.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Content-Type headers the server is sending for the .phtml files - chances are it's something the browser doesn't recognise.

Comment: Thanks for replay, could you please say more about your suggestion? 
In source of page i have only this:

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"><html><head><title></title></head><body></body></html>

But i think You have something else in mind?

Comment: You need to use Firebug (or similar) to check the "Content-Type" header the server is sending with the request - this doesn't show up in the page.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_headers#Responses and http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 0):

yes I don't remember Apache to be prepared for serving phtml files out-of-the-box.

I think you need to assert Content-Type is defined to text/html for the browser to render the file.